# Kivy Python3 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python-3.x, macos, apple-m1, kivymd

My simple Python3 script:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
class Datatable(MDDataTable):
    column_data = [('col1',dp(30)),('col2',dp(30)),('col3',dp(30)),]
    row_data = [('data1'),('data2'),('data3')]
class app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
app().run()
```

My simple kivy file ('lab.kv'):

```
BoxLayout:
    Datatable:
        id:datatable
```

I'm getting:

```
KeyError: 'container'
```

And:

```
self.ids.container.add_widget(self.header)
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Sorry, not allowed to post mostly code